# Is $x - 4.5$ algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, definition

From [Wikipedia's definition of algebraic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_expression)

> In mathematics, an algebraic expression is an expression built up from integer constants, variables, and the algebraic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and exponentiation by an exponent that is a rational number).

$4.5$ in $x - 4.5$ is not an integer, so it would be algebraic or not?

Comment: Looks like a *near* duplicate of the OP's earlier question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053814/is-xy-pi-an-algebraic-expression-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$X - \frac{9}{2} = \frac{2X - 9}{2}$$

so according to the definition, your expression is indeed an algebraic expression.

Comment: Its more precise to be rational algebraic expression

Comment: But what if when 4.5 is replaced by π, then still algebraic expression or not?

Comment: @user629353 then it certainly is not. Can you see why?

Comment: Because pi is irrational?